# Is there a way to 3D modeling with java on Rhinoceros

Tags: java, 3d-modelling, rhinoceros

I want to create the 3D model which can be expressed in sets of the points. I want to use java to calculate them and convert them into Rhino model. And I want to know how to join those points in to surface. I have calculated about 512*512 three dimensional points.

1. I want to know how can I script java to make a model on rhino.(If can't then is there other way?)
2. How to join lots of points in to one surface. ( Those points are the points on sphere.)

Thank you.

Comment: Any set with more than three points in it can be joined into many different surfaces. Which one do you need specifically?

Comment: It is the points which presents the shape on the sphere,

Comment: I know that problem,,,, I want to know how to connect the points with curvature 1 which is the curvature of the sphere